# How to force sorting of my tag list?

Tags: sorting, tags, evernote

My list of nested Evernote tags, after some careless tag creation and renaming, is no longer in alphabetical order. I know that if I remove each tag from its parent tag, and the re-add, it will be inserted in an alphabetically consistent location. But how can I force this without the trouble of dragging a few dozen tags around? Is there a "Re-sort tags alphabetically" option hiding in one of the menus?

Comment: Coincidentally, after asking the question I went into the options screen to see if I could find anything related to sort order. I don't think I changed any settings, but when I clicked OK all of my tags and notebooks were re-sorted. So perhaps this is a way to trigger re-sort - I'll look into it when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in the Windows Evernote client, going into `Tools-Options` and then dismissing the setting window by clicking `OK` forces a re-sort of both the notebooks and the tags. It also collapses sublists if there are any.